# TypeError: Person() takes no arguments

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to create class.when running this code every time getting error TypeError: Person() takes no arguments.
I don't know why arguments not passing to class

```
class Person:
    def _init_(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
    def myfun(self):
        print("my name is"+self.name)
        print("my age is"+self.age)

p1=Person("John",29)
p1.myfun()
```

Answer (score 20):

The constructor must be named `__init__`, not `_init_`.

Answer (score 2):

You should add 1 more `_` to init its magic-method and wraps by two underscores

https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self,name,age):
       self.name=name
       self.age=age
   def myfun(self):
       print("my name is"+self.name)
       print("my age is"+self.age)

p1=Person("John",29) ## use '29' in place of 29
p1.myfun()
```

it works